# Add values in database array in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have an array of database records which adds values in table view. Now i want to add @"All" object in the cell at index 0 so that when i select this value i can get all the records from database.

Comment: cell at index 0 or values as per the index?

Comment: what you want exact? at 1 index you want to set @"ALL"?

Comment: i have used groupby query for filteration now i want to add an object All at row  0 and then after the groupby values should get added. Now when i click to all i should get all the records from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code you can use where you are using query to group your data

```
NSDictionary *dicTemp = [[NSDictionary alloc]  initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ALL",@"Course", nil];
    [arrtimesList addObject:dicTemp];
```

The below code3 you can you code at didSelectRow

```
if([strName isEqualToString:@"ALL"])
{
    [self displayTimeList];
    [tblTimeslist  reloadData]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database method before the `sqlite3_step` statement add an object to the return array.

```
sqlite3_prepare(//prepare statements)
{
  //add object here
  [returnArray addObject:yourExtraObject];
  while(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
 {
    //add other objects here
  }
}
```

Comment: @Roma: is my answer helped you ? or you got any other ways ?

Comment: @Roma: thanks for your comment. You can share your solution as your answer,